# Tomcat's JspWriter not correctly encoding

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8, character-encoding, tomcat7

I have a default setup of Tomcat 7 and everything java-related configured to use utf-8.

This does not work (utf-8 characters are mangled):

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
    URL target = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
    Reader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(target.openStream()));
    StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
    char[] chrs = new char[1024 * 4];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = input.read(chrs)))
    {
        buffer.write(chrs, 0, n);
    }
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(buffer.toString());
    n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = reader.read(chrs)))
    {
        out.write(chrs, 0, n);
    } 
%>
```

This does, but logs IllegalStateExceptions:

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
    URL target = new URL("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
    Reader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(target.openStream()));
    StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
    char[] chrs = new char[1024 * 4];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = input.read(chrs)))
    {
        buffer.write(chrs, 0, n);
    }
    StringReader reader = new StringReader(buffer.toString());
    OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream());
    n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = reader.read(chrs)))
    {
        output.write(chrs, 0, n);
    }
%>
```

I've been searching but found no answers. Is this a bug in Tomcat, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This is the smallest example I could write that exhibited the problem without involving any databases. The real code looks nothing like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you construct [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) without specifying a charset as 2nd argument, then the platform default encoding will be used, which is often ISO-8859-1. You need to specify the same charset as specified in the response header of the target URL, which is UTF-8.

```
input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(target.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

The `IllegalStateException` is caused because you're doing this in a JSP instead of a Servlet. The JSP internally uses [`response.getWriter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29), but you're calling [`response.getOutputStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream%28%29) in a JSP *scriptlet*. This cannot be done simultaneously as explained in their javadocs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go when I have the chance.

Comment: Ten years late but I should probably clarify that this was an MVCE, not anything related to what the actual code does.